# how to select values from tables which start with prefix

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am new to oracle database, I have about 100 tables which starts with prefix like **PRE**:

```
CREATE TABLE PRE1 (
         name      VARCHAR2(15),
         value      VARCHAR2(15))
CREATE TABLE PRE2 (
         name      VARCHAR2(15),
         value      VARCHAR2(15))
CREATE TABLE PRE3 (
         name      VARCHAR2(15),
         value      VARCHAR2(15))
...
.....etc
```

I need in java to select name and values from all tables which start with prefix **PRE**; something like this:

```
select name, value from all tables which start with **PRE**
```

is this possible?

Now I would like to create select statement in java to get name and value from all tables which starts with **PRE**

Comment: That looks like a bad data model. That should be a single table with a _column_ identifying whether its "pre2" or "pre2"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name they are actually views, I put tables to make it easier

Comment: views or tables, same is true - if it was all inside one view (or table) the select would be almost obvious. Probably you want a to build a select like `select name,value from PRE1 union select name,value from PRE2 union select name, value from PRE3 union...`, eventually programmatically using the selects already suggested in below answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need this, the following can be a way:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE PRE1 (
  2           name      VARCHAR2(15),
  3           value      VARCHAR2(15))
  4  /

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE PRE2 (
  2           name      VARCHAR2(15),
  3           value      VARCHAR2(15))
  4  /

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE PRE3 (
  2           name      VARCHAR2(15),
  3           value      VARCHAR2(15))
  4  /

Table created.

SQL> select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'PRE%';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
PRE1
PRE2
PRE3

SQL>
```

Here I user `USER_TABLES`, while you may need `ALL_TABLES` or `DBA_TABLES`, depending on your needs and/or permissions.

However, at first sight, this does not seem the best possible design, so maybe you would re-consider it.

Answer (score 0):

see this article:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/29/sql-server-find-table-in-every-database-of-sql-server/

If not, follow that. Basically what he creates is a stored procedure which will search for every table name you specify in every database.

If you were to do this:

`select * from sys.tables where name like '%tablename%'`

or

```
Select name from DBname.sys.tables where name like '%info'
```

You would need to change the database every single time and if you have a lot, well you see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something interesting here if you can create your own types:

```
create or replace type tr as object (id varchar2(5), name varchar2(20));

create type tt as table of tr;
```

Then create function returning value of type `tt`:

```
create or replace function pre_list return tt pipelined is
  v tt;
begin
  for t in (select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'PRE%')
  loop
    execute immediate 'select tr(id, name) from '||t.table_name 
      bulk collect into v;
    for i in 1..v.count() loop
      pipe row (v(i));
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

And then you can call it like:

```
select * from table(pre_list());
```

That's all. Here is a small [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7d25657feb406f843020a35009a73ab0) with two tables, it should work for 100.